Plugging parameters into a Azure Data Factory pipeline from OData feed
I'm having trouble with a pipeline from an OData feed where I can't copy from this table without parameters. However, nothing I've plugged in to parameters has worked. I've read and tried the steps in this help manual :Data Factory How To but I continuously get the error below.

The {table} feed requires at least one of the following parameters: 'column1' (the name of a columnValue); 'column2' (a comma-separated list of columnValues); 'DateColumn1' (to get reports after this date); or 'DateColumn2' (to get reports before this date)

I'd appreciate it if anyone who has gotten parameters to work could help.
There's a ton of places to plug parameters in, and I'm not sure what counts as a parameter. For example my "column2" example calls for a comma separate list, am I supposed to use the parameter to call a list from somewhere, or can I just plug those values into the parameter form, as in the image?
Parameters
Linked Service

can you add the image of your linked service

I can, I just added a dummied version of what I have

Do curl  in terminal and check if you are getting the output?

As per your pipeline design, you are using pipeline parameters. For your requirement, you need to use dataset parameters. The dataset parameters are used for dynamic datasets.
Here is a sample demo on how to use dataset parameters in your case.
First create a string type parameter in your dataset.

In your path of the dataset, use the dataset parameter @dataset().dataset_param1. You can also use functions like concat() if you want to add any string to it.

As you have list of values that you want to pass to the dataset, you need to use a For-each loop.
Create a For-each activity with an expression @range(1,4). This expression will create a list of required values and the For loop will iterate through these.

Inside for-each, take your activity and add the dataset. For sample, I took a lookup activity. In the activity, it will ask to provide value to the created parameter. Here, you can pass the current item as per your requirement.

In each iteration during the pipeline run, the value will be passed to the dataset and the data from that value will be taken by the activity.
